# How to set action for UILocalNotification "CLOSE" button?

Tags: iphone, ios6, uilocalnotification

How to set action for UILocalNotification "CLOSE" action? If the user click the "CLOSE" button, at the time I will stop the audio player. Is it possible to do this?

I need some suggestions about this feature.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't detect the close or view button on an `UILocalNotification` because the notification is handled by iOS and not your app.

If the user decides to view the notification, your app will be started or brought to the foreground and then your app will receive the notification that the user used to open the app.

Comment: Thank you rckoenes. Any other way for local notification sound playing until the user click the "OK" (or) "CLOSE" button on the alert.

Comment: No you are limited to a maximum of 30 seconds of sound, you should really read the documentation of [`UILocalNotification `](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you very much rckoenes. You suggestion is more helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do this. We don't get any event for this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible you need to create on delegate method and in that method you need to stop your audio player or else when you are calling close button action at that time you need to stop your audio player.

Comment: Not this is not true, you can not detect the closer button pressed on a `UILocalNotification` your app will only be informed if the user opens your app via the notification and the notification used to open your app will be passed to the Application Delegate.

Comment: If the user click the "CLOSE" button, at the time I will stop the audio player. Is it possible to do this? then what is the meaning of this.. and for your kind information when application is going in background that time AVAudio player is taking care for all those things...

Comment: No if the `UILocalNotification` is presented as an `UIAlertView` and the user click close you will not be informed that the user ignored the notification.

Comment: Thank you guys. Really I want to show local notification as well as the sound playing until the user click the "CLOSE" (or) "OK" button on the alert. Any other way for do this task?